# Unable to paint the text in the Excel cellbox red

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have tried to paint the text in my Excel red, but I am unable to do that.
To clarify, I can do that by selecting the whole cell box, then change the font color to red, but I am unable to do that if I select the text instead of the cellbox. The text will temporarily change to red but the moment I try to deselect the text, it will automatically change back to black. This is very strange. Is this a bug of Excel or did I do something wrong? It doesn't happen to my other cells, only with number it seems. This is the [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15dNpTHjum8i9-r3pUDxyxp7D6ZWLSqbq/view?usp=sharing) in case it is needed for debuging
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the way Excel works.

If you have **Text** in a cell then you can apply a color format in two ways, either by applying it to the cell or to the characters in the cell by selecting them in the Formula Bar.

If you have a **Number** in a cell, you cannot use the Formula Bar to select some or all of the numerals to apply color formats.

*(Google Sheets works the same way)*

Comment: thanks for your timely reply, but I just don’t see the logic of it. Surely this complicate things unnecessarily?

Comment: @jxhyc  It is bothersome.  It is REALLY annoying if you want to format only certain numerals in a cell.

Comment: @jxhyc LibreOffice fortunately allows to change number's coloring.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio  thank you for the information.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent I just learned it today after opening the file on both Excel and LibreOfficeCalc. As you mentioned on your answer, with Excel I could only color a number if considered as text while I could do it in Calc without problem.